# D7 - Calling Form Into User Page

Tags: hooks, theming

We are trying to create a single page that has all the available user related forms available without have to click between pages.

We have been able to render some forms, like change password, but we are trying to include other forms rendered outside of the user module.

Specifically having trouble with rendering commerce_addressbook existing values and the 'add new address form'.
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook

Could anyone please outline the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is add a preprocess hook to the theme for the user page, and inject some new variables to the template.

Example:

In template.php:

`$variables['address_form'] = drupal_get_form('form_id', $arg1, $arg2, $arg3...);`

In your template tpl:

`<?php print render($address_form); ?>`

You will need to know the form id of the forms you want to call. The optional second argument to `drupal_get_form` will pass those arguments to the form, like say, user object, or user id. Each form will have their own requirements; some don't need any additional arguments at all.

Comment: How can I find out what arguments are required per form_id?